How to clear cache of a specific node & related to a specific field of a node
cache_clear_all('field:node:' . $nid, 'cache_field', TRUE);
cache_clear_all("field:node:{$nid}", 'cache_field');

Above is d7 code which is working fine in d7,
how to do same in drupal 9
Below is what i tried,
Trying to clear cache of a specific node.
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheTagsInvalidatorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;

function yellow_module_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'content_type') {
    $appt_nid = $node->id();
    $tags = ["field:node:{$appt_nid}"];

    $cacheTagsInvalidator = \Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator');
    $cacheTagsInvalidator->invalidateTags($tags);
  }
}

& also this 

Cache::invalidateTags($node->getCacheTags());

Trying to clearing cache for specif nodes field.
\Drupal::cache()->invalidateTags(["field:node:{$appt_nid}"]);
but it's not working.

I was able to clear cache of specific node like this
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->resetCache([$node->id()]);
